# Laravel Image link redirecting to login page in localhost

Tags: php, laravel, storage, laravel-artisan, public

I am new to php and trying to use a php code in my local system. The code is working fine but its images and static files are not loading properly. when i tried to debug the issue i found that the correct image link in browser renders the login page of the program.

This is a strange scenario and i am not finding any solutions in any platform.

The urls i am trying are `http://localhost:8000/image/banners/RG1.jpg` to access the public/image/banners directory.

I also have created a symlink and tried the url `http://localhost:8000/storage/images/user/RG1.jpg` to access image stored in storage/app/public/images/user directory. This also generates the same result. The screenshot of the output is attached below.
[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhMYP.png)

I guess there is some poblem in middleware or routing.

Comment: Can you check and provide any error messages if available in logs.

Comment: @ZaidMalek if you are talking about the laravel.log file i am not getting any error messages there at all

Comment: what does the picture show if you open it from your ide in the public/storage folder? is the login page shown a page or a picture of the page??

Comment: @suxgri the picture loads correctly in the IDE with no problems encountered

Comment: strange.. i would try testing by removing all routes middlewares in web.php file, then you could also shows the web php file and config filesystem here in your question

Answer (score -1):

you tried this command

for link folder

```
php artisan storage:link
```

then use

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/user/RG1.jpg') }}">
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this but it is not working

Answer (score -1):

make sure you'r working on the same port and also make sure you've done `php artisan storage:link`.
second methode try accessing via the public folder

```
http://localhost/[PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME]/public/[REST_OF_IMG_PATH]
or in your case 
http://localhost:8000/[PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME]/public/[REST_OF_IMG_PATH]
```

also try to delete the link that is made in the public folder and redo
`php artisan storage:link`.
and `php artisan optimize`.

Comment: using your method gives 404 error instead of the login page

Comment: now try uploading the image again after doing `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: if it also gives an error 404 check if the image is actually in the folder

Comment: The `public` folder should never show up in any URL. It should be the project's "DocumentRoot"

Answer (score -1):

use `php artisan serve` and check `.env` file.

into `.env` file have

`APP_URL=localhost:8000` change to

`APP_URL=127.0.0.1:8000`

delete `/storage` in `/public` directory
and try to `php artisan storage:link`

Answer (score -1):

please check the rewrite URL in htaccess files .

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/logo.png') }}" alt="" />
```

Here i saved images in the public folder , then images  folder then image. Try the same way

.htaccess files inside public folder

Options -MultiViews -Indexes

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

### never deliver .git folders, .gitIgnore
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.git+ - [R=404,L]

# 2nd line of defense (if no mod_rewrite)
RedirectMatch 404 ^(.*/)?\.git+
```

then `php artisan optimize`